# How to open a file using specific application in cygwin?

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, default, notepad

I know that you can open programs in `cygwin` using `cygstart`.

I also know that you can open files in a similar fashion.  However, I would like to open a file *using* a specific program.  For example, I want to open a text file using sublime and I try:

```
cygstart -a <nameoffile.txt> sublime_text
```

But this just opens the default.

I also tried:

```
cygstart -o <nameoffile.txt> sublime_text
```

But this also opens the default application (notepad).

I read the man pages, and those two things seem to be the only commands that might be reasonable for this.
How to open a file using specific application in cygwin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usually just use the program executable file itself.  If it's in your PATH, then just do:

`<program exe> <name of file to open>&`

The `&` is necessary to make it a background process, otherwise Cygwin will wait for the program to end before it'll let you use the console again.

If it's not in your PATH, you can either create a symbolic link to it using `ln -s`, putting the symbolic link in your PATH, or specify the full path on the command line.